# Duplicate column in DataTable when adding row

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I create a DataTable and bind it to a DataGrid. My DataSource consist of one Table (FooTable) which consist of one column (FooName).

The following codes runs fine - except that each time I add a new row, there is a duplicate Column fill in with the same data, which I don't know how to get rid of. See below image and code. I have only one FooName column and a duplicate column comes out.

[image]

```
/* Create a DataGrid dg1 */
DataGrid dg1 = new DataGrid();
DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
col = new DataGridTextColumn();
colA.Binding = new Binding("FooName");
colA.Header = "FooName";
dg1.Columns.Add(colA);
dataGrid1.Children.Add(dg1);

/* Create a DataTable and bind it to DataGrid */
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
string sqlStr = @"SELECT * FROM FooTable";
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand(sqlStr, conn);
da.Fill(ds, "FooTable");
dt = ds.Tables["FooTable"];
DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
newRow["FooName"] = "Donkey";
dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
dg1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try setting AutoGenerateColumns to false

```
 dg1.AutoGenerateColumns = false
```

Comment: Haha, 34 seconds earlier than me, nice one :D

Comment: Yet another quick-draw question.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
dg1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Should do the work for you. For now the datagrid automatically generates the columns AND adds the one you asked